# Syntax error in "select where not exists" query

Tags: sql, mysql

I am working on a database project. I can successfully read an event XML feed from another website and place it into the database (via php).

`internal_id` is controlled by me and needed `externalinstance_id` is pulled from the feed and I want to insert it if it does not exist.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgrYE.png)

I am trying to achieve that the events have their own `eventinstance_id` (I want to use this to insert only unique), and I have my own `internal_id`. How do I "insert if `external_id` is not in the database" (ignore duplicated)?

I have tried to use a select where not exists in phpmyadmin (trying to build the query), however, when I perform the query I get this SQL syntax error on phpmyadmin:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vMIy.png)

I want to insert if there isn't a `internal_id` of 2 for example.

I'm using:

- Win 7
- Apache 2.4.18
- PHP 7.0.6
- PHP EXT mysqli
- phpmyadmin 4.5.1

Comment: You can set the table column as UNIQUE. MySQL won't let you add new records with same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make eventinstance_id as Unique Id and use can use "INSERT IGNORE" QUERY.
It will insert only unique values.

Example :- `INSERT IGNORE INTO table (pid,uid,data) VALUES (1,34,56);`
Where pid is primary key and uid is unique key.

Below you can find more details on Insert Ignore
["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)